# I want to add custom shortcode only on specific page on WordPress

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress-theming

I need to add custom shortcode only on the specific page through the `header.php`

This is confusing me a bit since I've tried to put `is_page()` only in `if()` but it doesn't work. I need from my code to do the following:

Example code is here:

```
$page = 'page_slug';
if (is_page($page)) {
   do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
}
```

From some reason, this doesn't work.

Comment: Why not just leave off the `else` ?

Comment: I try that but doesn't work. Even I tried to create a blank function and just call them in else, but nothing.

Comment: What is it that you want? If it goes into the ``else`` part it is doing nothing. Or do youwant the script to terminate? Question is not clear what the expected result should be.

Comment: `If` that's the whole code, `then` i am afraid that `get_page()` and `do_shortcode()` are not even defined

Comment: I want to that shortcode is appear on just one page, and on every other page don't.

Comment: Then how does get_page($page) function looks like? What is it returning?

Comment: *"I want to that shortcode is appear on just one page, and on every other page don't."* - leaving off the else would do that. There's something else you're not showing us. Is this WordPress by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the function `get_page` in the `if` statement. Even though it is evaluated to false, the function is executed, I bet the problem comes from that.

Consider changing `get_page` to have it only returning boolean but not doing anyhting else.

Of course, then you can leave only the `if` statement and get rid of the `else`.

**EDIT:** Here's an [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9dee9e15ebdbc10ecd04ff455961e26c0d36b312).
`else` statement is empty, there shouldn't be anything but "bar" is printed as the function is executed to determine if `if` statement should be entered or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `else` as your code doesn't return or echo result

```
$page = '4827';
if (get_page($page)) {
  echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]');
}
```